# Karate Runner hangs at waiting for parallel features to complete

Tags: maven, testing, karate

I am trying to execute some tests using Karate Runner -

```
@KarateOptions(tags = {"~@ignore"}) 
//@KarateOptions(features = "examples/test.feature")
public class KarateTestRunner {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {        
        //TestBase.beforeClass();
    } 

    @Test
    public void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner.parallel(getClass(), 5);
        generateReport(results.getReportDir());
        assertTrue(results.getErrorMessages(), results.getFailCount() == 0);        
    }
}
```

When I try to execute my tests:

```
-mvn test -Dtest=KarateTestRunner -DfailIfNoTests=false
```

It displays -

```
{ ","type":"log","logger":"com.intuit.karate.Runner","thread":"main","level":"INFO","categories":[],"msg":"waiting for parallel features to complete ..." }
```

And it hangs here. No logs.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 2):

There was an [issue (#1258)](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1258) related with multi-thread.
When you try to run, sometimes chrome websocket answer back before the karate can handle that.

Fixed at 0.9.6 onward.

Answer (score 0):

We did have an issue in 0.9.4 - so can you try with 0.9.5.RC5 and confirm.

Here is the issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/967

Comment: Was already using 0.9.5.RC5. The issue still exists.Please help me here.

Comment: @ysn 3 things. a) run using the JUnit runner (not parallel runner) and you will find which part of your script has the error b) build from source and let us know if fixed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide c) if you still have a problem it is very important you replicate it for us to fix: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue